# Get Root mean squared error (RMSE) for a period

Tags: python, mse

I have two time series (forecast and realization) and both start as of 2003 until today. I need to calculate the RMSE for each month and for each year. Could you please help me with the code. I used `np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(actual, forecast))` but it gives RMSE for the whole set.
Many thanks!

The data loos like this [image]

Comment: I think you need to look into slicing

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data is a `pandas` dataframe. If so, you want to group by months and then aggregate by `rmse`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
df["differ"] = df["Forecast"] - df["Actual"]
rmseser = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month']).differ.agg(lambda x: sqrt(np.sum(x * x))
```

Comment: it seems that it's not working at my end - I got "'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'differ'"